# Use a currency format different than what windows is set to

Tags: c#, .net

I have a customer who wants to keep their computer localized to their country (Brazil).  They want the language and regional settings to all be Brazilian.  My app, however, needs to work on US Dollars and show all currency as US Dollars.  Everything else (Language, Date Format) needs to be Brazilian.

What would be an easy way to handle this?  My app is already aware of different regions, and works in different countries.  It's a .net 4.0 app, so I'm thinking I can just change the Currency formatting programmatically when the app starts.  Is this a good way to go about this?

Comment: can you give and or show an example of what you have you could do this by code by doing the following for example
`int MyInt = 100;`
 `string MyString = MyInt.ToString("C");`
results = `$100.00`[Globalization Step-By-Step](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688126.aspx)

Comment: @aircan, should the US decimal mark (period) be used for amounts, with the number preceded by the $ sign? Or should it use the Brazil decimal mark (comma), with the number preceded by a $ sign? In other words, should a thousand dollars and twentythree cents be shown as $1,000.23 or $1.000,23?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you use `decimal` as the type for currency, you can use `CultureInfo` object and pass it along in your `ToString()` method. Something like this:

```
decimal amount = 9.95m;
string amountString = amount.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: This would work if all data bindings are done to string properties, allowing to inject your own formatting. If data bindings are done to decimal properties, the 'decimal to string' conversion done by WPF will still use the machine culture.

Comment: The idea is to use `CultureInfo` where it's needed. The example, of course, works only under the stated assumption and in this specific case - the best we can do without specifics of the implementation in the app.

Answer (score 2):

When your program starts, replace `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat` with the `NumberFormat` from the en-US culture:

```
// On startup:
CultureInfo currentCulture = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
currentCulture.NumberFormat = new CultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
```

Note: This will affect all numeric formats, not just currency formats. If you wanted to, you could copy over just the currency-related properties in `NumberFormat`.

Comment: I guess `CurrencySymbol` can *only* be set like `currentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = new CultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol;` +1

Comment: @user469104: No, CurrentUICulture should *not* be changed if the UI language needs to remain Brazilian.